# Prometheus metrics loss during restarts

Tags: prometheus, instrumentation

I have few Prometheus Gauge and Counters in my Python application and I am registering them like this:

```
visits = Gauge('visit_count', 'No. of connected customers', ['mobile'])
start_http_server(addr='X.X.X.X',port=8001)
```

Everything works fine up until I need to restart my python application for any reason. The moment I restart the app, all metrics gets deleted.

How can I maintain the value of these metrics during restart?

Comment: What so you mean by getting deleted? Metrics that where scraped by Prometheus are store by it.

Comment: That's what I understand too, but when I restart my Python application, and query prometheus, it returns empty result

Comment: How are you querying it? Can you still query older values? Do you know about metrics stalyness?

Comment: I am querying it through the Prometheus UI by searching for the metrics name. I did not understand what is metrics stalyness?

Comment: If you are using their ui, try graph tab. [Staleness](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness)

Comment: Yes, I am trying graph tab. Also, going through few documentation, I thought the reason might be because I am not using Collector Registry, so I added that logic, but now nothing is getting instrumented in the first place

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254808/discussion-between-ankit-prabhatkumar-and-markalex).